# Why does std::is_function evaluate to false when using on a dereferenced function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, type-traits

I am trying to use `std::is_function` to determine if a variable is a function pointer.

When running the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    typedef int(*functionpointer)();

    functionpointer pmain = main;

    cout << typeid(functionpointer).name() << " "<< is_function<functionpointer>::value << endl;
    cout << typeid(decltype(pmain)).name() << " " << is_function<decltype(pmain)>::value << endl;

    cout << typeid(decltype(main)).name() << " " << is_function<decltype(main)>::value << endl;
    cout << typeid(decltype(*pmain)).name() << " " << is_function<decltype(*pmain)>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
PFivE 0
PFivE 0
FivE 1
FivE 0
```

Can anybody with insight explain why the last expression of `std::is_function` evaluates to false?

(Code tested under g++4.7, g++4.8 and clang++3.2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because `decltype(*pmain)` yield a *reference* to a function type, for which `std::function` is `false` as intended. Try:

```
is_function<remove_reference<decltype(*pmain)>::type>::value
```

BTW: ISO C++ forbids to take the address of ::main()